# To create a new UIWindow over the main window

Tags: ios, uiwindow

In my app I want to create a new `UIWindow` over the main UIWindow, And I wrote as following, but it don't works.
first, i create a `UIWindow` as the main window, and then make it key and visible, and then create a new `UIWindow` overlay, but nothing happens.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    UIWindow *window1 = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    window1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    window1.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
    [window1 makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: why it does work for me, my Xcode is V5.0

Comment: I tried it in xCode 4.6 & 5 and it works.

Comment: and your simulator version?

Comment: in modern iOS this is now **all wrong** .. https://noahgilmore.com/blog/uiwindowscene-black-screen/

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
UIWindow *window1 = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
window1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
window1.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
[window1 makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Finally I know why it doesn't work, because window1 is a method var, and it will lost after the method executed. So I declare a new @property for it, as

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window2;
```

and 
change the code like

```
UIWindow *window2 = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 320)];
window2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
window2.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
self.window2 = window2;
[window2 makeKeyAndVisible];
```

it works!

Comment: Why not: `self.window2 = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 320)];
self.window2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.window2.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
[self.window2 makeKeyAndVisible];` ?

Comment: It's almost the same here, but usually – and mostly, especially in concurrent-threads situations – it's a good idea to fully populate object instance with all its properties and after that, assign to an owning property. In case some other thread would begin changing the `self.window2` properties while primary thread is in the middle of the block, you'd have no idea about final properties of an object assigned – could be a mixture of many different alternative states.

Comment: How do i dismiss that window ?

Comment: ten yrs later it's all different: https://noahgilmore.com/blog/uiwindowscene-black-screen/

Answer (score 14):

If you are using a window scene try this:

```
private var overlayWindow: UIWindow!

if let currentWindowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as?  UIWindowScene {
        overlayWindow = UIWindow(windowScene: currentWindowScene)
    }
overlayWindow.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert
overlayWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()//your controller or navController
overlayWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: The `UIWindow(windowScene:)` initializer was key to making this work, thank you!

Comment: This is the only answer that worked in iOS 15 properly.

Answer (score 13):

### Xcode 8 + Swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var coveringWindow: UIWindow?
    
    func coverEverything() {
        coveringWindow = UIWindow(frame: (view.window?.frame)!)
        
        if let coveringWindow = coveringWindow {
            coveringWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
            coveringWindow.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwindow), to receive events that do not have a relevant coordinate value, such as keyboard entry, make it `key` instead of merely `!` `isHidden`:

```
coveringWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

You can even control the transparency of its background, for a smoke effect:

```
coveringWindow.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
```

*Note that such window needs to handle orientation changes.*

Comment: thanks for that.  One thing ... _"Note that such window needs to handle orientation changes."_ it would seem that modern iOS now does that automatically.  What do you think?  Since perhaps iOS9 ?

Comment: I tried it, and it seems not to work in iOS 13, the window just won't appear on the screen. And if I set ViewController as its root, I get error message "Manually adding the rootViewController's view to the view hierarchy is no longer supported. Please allow UIWindow to add the rootViewController's view to the view hierarchy itself."

Answer (score 11):

Your `window1` object is a local variable, when the code runs out of this method, this object does not exist any more. Any `UIWindow` object we created will be add to the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]`, but this array only keeps a weak reference to any `UIWindow` object, so it's up to your own code to keep the window object existing. Why apple implemented it like this, I guess, is `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` object exists as long as the app runs, doing so to avoid keeping the `UIWindow` objects which only needs to exist for a while living in the memory "forever".

What's more, your code could run with MRC.

Answer (score 5):

**SWIFT 5**

In iOS13 and higher you must create `UIWindow` with `windowScene:` initializer as follows `let overlayWindow = UIWindow(windowScene: YourScene)`. For lower iOS versions you should use `frame:` initializer as follows `let overlayWindow = UIWindow(frame: YourFrame)`.

After creating `UIWindow` instance you can use code to display window as is written in @Nick Greg answer:

> ```
> overlayWindow.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert
> overlayWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()//your controller or navController
> overlayWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
> ```

Comment: While not incorrect, this answer is identical to the NickGreg answer.  To achieve an overlay window, simply **copy and paste the code form the NickGreg answer**.  Nothing needs to be changed from the NickGreg answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

To avoid memory leak, I prefer to initialise my custom window in this way, as proposed by Apple :

> If you want to provide a custom window for your app, you must implement the getter method of this property and use it to create and return your custom window.

Example:

```
var myCustomWindow: UIWindow? = CustomWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let mainController: MainViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! MainViewController
    self.myCustomWindow?.rootViewController = mainController
    self.myCustomWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just need to change shared window ViewController in swift 5

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourViewController)
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a `UIView` on mainWindow not another `UIWindow` like...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    UIView * viewAlert = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    viewAlert.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubView:viewAlert];
    /* or you can use following..
    [self.window addSubView:viewAlert];
    */
    [viewAlert release]; //FOR NON ARC
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: sorry bohan, I dont have any idea because i am working with view only. Is it working or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
func createAdsWindow(){
    let frame = CGRect.init(0, UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 60, UIScreen.main.bounds.width, 60)
    adsWindow = UIWindow.init(frame: frame)
    adsWindow!.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorBackground)
    let adsViewController = UIViewController.init()
    adsViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    adsWindow?.rootViewController = adsViewController
    adsWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: 2)
    adsWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In swift a new `UIWindow` can be added as follows..

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var viewController: ViewController?
    var navigationController: UINavigationController?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.viewController = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle())
        self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.viewController!)
        self.window!.rootViewController = self.navigationController
        //  self.window!.addSubview(self.viewController!.view)
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }

    //Other methods..
}
```