# How to add countdowntimer which will run in whole iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I need to add a global timer of 60 minutes in the application which will show in all ViewControllers. 
But not able to implement this feature.

I have implemented timer in one ViewController till now.
Here is my code:

```
 var timerCount = 3600
var timer = Timer()
 timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func update() {

    if(timerCount > 0){
        let minutes = String(timerCount / 60)
        let seconds = String(timerCount % 60)
        timeLbl.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        timerCount -= 1
    }
    else {
        timer.invalidate()
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigateViewController")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

    }

}
```

I need to show this timer value in every ViewController of the application.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to implement this feature"? Please be more specific. What is not working? Do you receive an error?

Comment: what you mean by all screen

Comment: Means I have created timer and its working. But how to make it global,and show the result in all viewcontroller

Comment: Make a protocol and implement delegate functions in the viewcontrollers.

Comment: Why you need this process in all view you can use NSnotifications  when timer invalidated

Comment: Its in project scope to show timer on top of every screen.......

Comment: If you use pods then you can create static timer with AsyncTimer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Create  class TimerManager

class TimerManager {
    var timerCount = 3600

       static let sharedInstance = TimerManager()
    var timer: Timer?

    init() {

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }

    @objc func update() {
        if(timerCount > 0){
            let minutes = String(timerCount / 60)
            let seconds = String(timerCount % 60)
            timerCount -= 1
        }
        else {
            self.timer?.invalidate()


        }
    }


}


// At view Controller   you can access  timerCount

  print(TimerManager.sharedInstance.timerCount)
```

Comment: Will this be a NSObject class? And how to call method to start timer ?

Comment: Just timer will start after you sharedInstance

Comment: It shows only Single value .E.g I if call print method in Viewcontroller A ==> ViewDidLoad , then it is not updating

Answer (score 0):

You should display it in a separate UIWindow instance. Put the label in a separate View Controller and refer to answer 42 from this post:
[To create a new UIWindow over the main window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995526/to-create-a-new-uiwindow-over-the-main-window)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create  class TimerManager

class TimerManager {
    var timerCount = 3600

       static let sharedInstance = TimerManager()
    var timer: Timer!

    init() {

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    }

    @objc func update() {
        if(timerCount > 0){
            let minutes = String(timerCount / 60)
            let seconds = String(timerCount % 60)
            timerCount -= 1
        }
        else {
            self.timer?.invalidate()


        }
    }


}


// At view Controller   you can access  timerCount

  print(TimerManager.sharedInstance.timerCount)
```

Comment: Will this be a NSObject class? And how to call method to start timer ?

Comment: Welcome to SO!. You might want to explain how your code solves the problem for OP. I suggest you edit your post and improve it.

Comment: you've missed the most important part: how to update the VC's with the current time.
@vickydutta, you can have the `update` method send a notification and have all the VC register for it. when a VC gets a notification from the timer it is updating the timeLbl.