# Keep UIView from one controller to another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

I am using https://github.com/ali-ehsan/GIFProgressHUD as a loading spinner across my app but it seems to only be attached to a single view, so if I'm loading from a login screen to the home screen, during the transition this progress hud will disappear automatically.

Is there a way I can get a view to stay between screens kinda like a activity indicator ?

I'm developing in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add (attach) your progress view to the main window of the application instead of a subview of the controller or view that is being removed when you transition.

#### A - use KVC

```
id appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UIWindow *keyWindow = [appDelegate valueForKey:@"window"];
```

#### B - use keywindow property of UIApplication

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

This property holds the UIWindow object that is most recently sent the makeKeyAndVisible message.

#### C - use windows property of UIApplication

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows].lastObject;
```

**Suggestion:** just tag your progress view so you can easily find it later when you need to remove it.

**UPDATE:**
Now that you have the main window (the top most view in the hierarchy), you can add any type of stack object you like (a view, label, activity indicator, etc.) just like you would to any `UIView`.

```
// Easiest and most readable way to get the key window
UIWindow *keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow; 

UIView *testview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
testview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[keyWindow addSubview:testview];

testview.center = keyWindow.center;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As a last resort if you are navigating in ways outside of traditional `UIViewController` transitions and presentations, you can always **add a new window** to the stack [as seen here in this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995526/to-create-a-new-uiwindow-over-the-main-window)

If the issue of the disappearing view persists you might want to try changing the way in which you navigate through your views / controllers **OR** pass references between the controllers to allow this "disappearing" view to live on.

[Another reference regarding this type of navigation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774003/changing-root-view-controller-of-a-ios-window)

Comment: This doesnt work. I know how to get the top window. The problem is that while transitioning between controllers, the previous top controller that had the "spinner" is gone, so it disappears

Comment: Of course it does.. along with the now previous controller. You can't expect the spinner to stay around once it's parent is removed. Find another way to attach the spinner to something that *doesn't get removed* when you transition - hence my top most window suggestion

Comment: I obviously don't know how to attach it to the window then. I tried using option B. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: No problem. Using the key window is a nice way to allow content to stay put during things such as controller transitions. Test it out with some controller navigation and you can see how it stays on top above your other content.

Comment: Could this not be working because I am switching the root view controller?

Comment: I think I was able to use that window snippet however I think we moved towards a different approach for these spinners. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem glad you got it working - if you felt this solved your issue if you could accept the answer please. Either way happy coding!