# How to Push ViewController in new window

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I need to push `viewController` in the new window by code. I am doing below code but its not working.

```
let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
nc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
win.rootViewController = nc

win.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1
win.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Does anyone have idea, how to push a viewController in new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Swift 5.x**

Below code works

took global variable:

```
var window2 : UIWindow?
```

Modified code with below

```
let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let nc = UINavigationController()
nc.pushViewController(self, animated: true)
nc.navigationBar.isHidden = true
nc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
win.rootViewController = nc
window2 = win
win.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1
win.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And dismiss new window I did below

```
if let nc = window2?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    nc.popViewController(animated: true)
}

window2?.resignKey()
window2 = nil
```

---

**Note:** It is not showing push and pop default animation, rather currently it is working w/o any kind of animation.

**Ref :** [To create a new UIWindow over the main window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995526/to-create-a-new-uiwindow-over-the-main-window)